# Read Firestore from GCP Cloud Function

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a basic function written in Go and deployed to GCP (**not a Firebase Cloud Function, a GCP Cloud Function**). I need this function to access a single collection in Firestore to retrieve a token to send a notification via FCM.

Under IAM & ADMIN > IAM I have a Service Account that has the following permissions: Cloud Datastore User, Cloud Functions Invoker, Cloud Functions Service Agent, Editor, Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent, Firebase Cloud Messaging Admin, Service Account Token Creator, Service Account User, Viewer

Under my function > Permissions I have this service account listed as a principal with the following permissions: Cloud Functions Admin, Cloud Functions Invoker, Cloud Functions Service Agent, Editor, Firebase Admin

I've verified in the function details that the correct service account is attached to this function, but I still get this error:

```
{"error":"rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions."}
```

The function creates the Firestore client without an issue, but it cannot read any of the documents:

```golang
// setting the client
func _setFirestoreClient(ctx context.Context) (firestore.Client, error) {
    if client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, _projectId); err != nil {
        return firestore.Client{}, err
    } else {
        return *client, err
    }
}
// using the client
data, err := firestoreClient.Collection("tokens").Doc(requestBody.ReceiverUserUid).Get(ctx)
```

Is there any solid source of documentation on how to read Firestore documents from GCP? I'm not entirely sure how to proceed as I'm 99% sure I have the correct permissions in place - honestly I probably have unnecessary permissions included as well - and my Firestore security rules allow reads from authenticated users so the Firebase Admin SDK should be able to read this without any issue.

Please advise.

EDIT

Apologies for not including enough information. This is the function file:

```golang
package sendnotification

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "firebase.google.com/go/messaging"
)

func SendNotification(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    requestBody, err := _parseRequest(w, req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error and return
    }
    
    ctx := context.Background()
    var firestoreClient firestore.Client

    if client, err := _setFirestoreClient(ctx); err != nil {
        // handle error and reurn
    } else {
        firestoreClient = client
        defer firestoreClient.Close()
    }

    var tokenData TokenDocument
    data, err := firestoreClient.Collection("tokens").Doc(requestBody.ReceiverUserUid).Get(ctx)
    
    // function continues to send data through FCM
}
```

This all works locally where I've configured gcloud with my credentials, so when I start up a local server and hit the endpoint for this function I can read Firestore without any issues

Comment: Your post does not show the imports or how you are authorizing the Firestore client. I do not see a problem with the code you posted. Include more code and show the exact entire error message. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In your post you mention two service accounts. Only one matters. Remove the one that is not attached to your function or explain why both matter. For problems like this, I recommend writing a local application that uses the same service account and testing it locally instead of in a cloud function.

Comment: Your app, as written, needs the IAM permission `datastore.entities.get` and `datastore.entities.list`. The IAM role `roles/datastore.user` (Cloud Datastore User) has the required permissions. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#predefined_roles Your function has way too many IAM roles assigned. The role `Editor` has those permissions, so you do are not missing a permission problem. My guess is that you are setting up the SDK incorrectly.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've edited to show the imports and how I'm initializing the SDK, thank you for giving some attention to this. I have the Cloud Datastore User role added but that didn't seem to do the trick. I'm wondering why this works locally on my machine but not in the cloud.

Comment: Only two ideas: 1) The project ID is wrong. 2) the value of `requestBody.ReceiverUserUid` is invalid.

Comment: On top of John's comment - can  you check that 1) the service account is set correctly, and the cloud function is run the proper service account (you might like to post code how you deploy the cloud function, so it becomes visible); 2) the projects and IAM roles are set correctly (if the firestore is in a different project than the cloud function, the IAM roles should take that into account).

Comment: @JohnHanley your ideas were almost spot on. Turns out I had created a second project that wasn't part of the Firebase project for some cloud functions a few months ago, and those cloud functions never access Firestore so I never caught the error. I switched my project ID in the GCP CLI and redeployed, and everything worked fine.

Comment: @al-dann turns out the project ID wasn't set correctly in my CLI, thanks for pointing out where things could be going wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that about 3 months ago I had created a second project to contain all the cloud function APIs I was creating. That project wasn't part of the Firebase project, and therefore had no access to Firestore. I switched the project ID in my GCP CLI like so:

```bash
gcloud config set project <project-id>
```

Then I redeployed my function to the cloud and was able to access Firestore without needing to set additional IAM roles for the Service Account. The default service account for the Firebase project already had permission to read data from Firestore.